# Spring Boot with Azure key vault appl run error : RuntimeException: Max retries 3 times exceeded

Tags: spring-boot, maven, azure-keyvault

I have a spring boot app which uses azure key vault. The app has been running fine. Recently I have upgraded some jar files and changed the pom.xml. However after the upgrade my app is not coming up. I am getting the below error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Max retries 3 times exceeded. Error Details: connect timed out

at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.lambda$attemptAsync$1(RetryPolicy.java:119)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:185)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:545)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:545)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:185)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:134)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:48)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1705)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:171)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2269)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:143)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:182)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryPredicate.java:82)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:156)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:398)
at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:514)
at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:501)
at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:413)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:550)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1372)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1246)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1286)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475)
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1664)
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient.getSecretWithResponse(SecretClient.java:171)
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient.getSecret(SecretClient.java:150)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultOperation.get(KeyVaultOperation.java:100)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultPropertySource.getProperty(KeyVaultPropertySource.java:27)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.merge(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:236)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.merge(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:207)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:189)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.initialize(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:124)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener$DelegatingEnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.initialize(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:441)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:626)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.lambda$checkIMDSAvailable$14(IdentityClient.java:462)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:91)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:126)


... 52 common frames omittedu2028 [emju-edis-connector,,,,,] [afd1de3e-eb35-455c-4b21-b301] [16] [main] ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
   2021-10-18T11:32:28.11+0000 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
```

Below is the relevant section (dependencies) from the pom.xml file :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hectorclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hectorclient.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
            <artifactId>qpid-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.47.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-common</artifactId>
            <version>${io-netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>${io-netty.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${io-netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
            <version>${io-netty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-servicebus-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${servicebus.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
                    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>9.18</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-servicebus</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.jwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-jwt-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.jwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-jwt-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.15.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.44.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-as</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zzzzzz</groupId>
                <artifactId>pppp-aaaa</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
                <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

This is surely caused because I have updated the dependencies but I am unable to locate the issue. Can anyone please help me out.

Got some similar posts at :

[GitHub Issue Link-1](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/issues/745)

[GitHub Issue Link-2](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/issues/380)

But nothing fruitful I could infer from there.

Comment: The real problem is this:

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

It means that the connection to the Azure Key Vault was unsuccessful.  Has anything changed in your network?  It might be helpful to capture a network trace to determine if the client is able to connect to the Key Vault.

Comment: @MattSmall Nothing changed in n/w. It is at it was .. other apps which are not updated ..with same key vault config are connecting still.